# function calls from command line, using emacsclient

Tags: emacsclient, functions

I used to read my emails from command line with `emacs -f gnus`. To read my emails using emacsclient, I'm doing `emacsclient -c --eval '(gnus)'`. Just want to know, is there a simpler alternative to that? Something that will be closer to `emacs -f gnus`? In fact, what is the proper way to call an emacs functions from command line using emacsclient?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `--eval` is the way to go. If `-f`/`--funcall` were supported then `emacsclient --help` would mention it. Alternatively ask the Emacs maintainers to implement `--funcall` too. I cannot see a reason why `emacsclient` should not support it when `emacs` does.